# Can I use a VLookup that includes dates and tab names?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

It's been a little while so I'm blaming this on being rusty... :-)
I have a main sheet with all my current month data on it (this is raw data) . I then have unique day tabs, for example tabs 1-30. What I am trying to do is to look for a matching location on the day (DATE) tabs, then return the value in column 3 from the main sheet to the day sheet.

```
So if I had in main:
Location Name | Date |  Some Value
loc1           01/01      4
loc2           01/02      3

In my day 1 Tab I'd want to see:
Location Name |Same Value From Main|
loc1             4
loc2            (blank/NA...etc...)
```

I only want to pull the value from the main sheet to the day tab when the day tab and the date (day of month) are equal.

This is what I have so far, but I feel something is off:
`=VLOOKUP(A2,Main!A2:H4364,8,FALSE)`

Because I get values for all days and all locations on all tabs....but that's wrong. Thanks for any help.
:-)

Comment: Use sumifs on a two column lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each Date sheet in column B (assuming loc1 etc is in ColA) put the following and drag down.

UPDATED:

```
=IF(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)*1=DAY(Main!B2),VLOOKUP(A1,Main!A1:C11,3,FALSE),NA())
```

This part matches on the sheet name if the workbook is saved and the *1 converts to an integer

```
MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)*1
```

And this parses out the day in the main sheet for the match

```
DAY(Main!B2)
```

Each day layout:

[image: Daily layout]

Main sheet layout

[image: Main sheet layout]

Comment: Is there only ever a month at a time then?

Comment: Updated as per instruction that day is parsed as sheet name and not entire date. This assumes therefore only a month at a time present and enough sheets to match the number of days in the current month.

Comment: QHar, yes, assumptions correct. the *1 did the trick. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

am assuming that your date is in column 8. You do a vlookup and find the date first. Then you extract the day from the date.. If the day is equal to 1 then you write the 'Some value' there. (Assuming Some value is column 8)

```
=IF(DAY(VLOOKUP A2,Main!A2:H4364, 8,FALSE))=1,VLOOKUP(A2,Main!A2:H4364, 2,FALSE), "Not here")
```

Edit

```
=IF(DAY(TEXT(VLOOKUP( A2,Main!$A$2:$H$4364, 2,FALSE), "mm/dd/yyyy"))=1,VLOOKUP(A2,Main!A2:$H$4364, 8,FALSE), "Not here")
```

Comment: For all rows? Are you sure you have matches?

Comment: For all rows? Are you sure you have matches?

Comment: Edited and added a new formula